# How to move the "create new account" higher in woocommerce

Tags: plugins

I'm sorry if this turns out to be a stupid question, but I can't seem to find a way how to force the checkbox for "create new account" appear before everything else. I looked inside the `form-checkout.php` file in `theme/woocommerce/checkout` folder but can't make out which file should I go and look for this, so any help is appreciated. For reference my form-check.php looks like this:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->show_messages();
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', $checkout );
// If checkout registration is disabled and not logged in, the user cannot checkout
if ( ! $checkout->enable_signup && ! $checkout->enable_guest_checkout && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_must_be_logged_in_message', __( 'You must be logged in to checkout.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    return;
}
// filter hook for include new pages inside the payment method
$get_checkout_url = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_url', $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url() ); ?>
<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( $get_checkout_url ); ?>">
    <?php if ( sizeof( $checkout->checkout_fields ) > 0 ) : ?>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' ); ?>
        <div class="col2-set" id="customer_details">
            <div class="col-1">
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ); ?>
        <h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php _e( 'Your order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' ); ?>
</form>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', $checkout ); ?>
```

[image]

Comment: jeez, a downvote - care to explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by customizing the `form-billing.php` template, just move this part:

```
<?php if (!is_user_logged_in() && get_option('woocommerce_enable_signup_and_login_from_checkout')=="yes") : ?>
//more code..
<?php endif; ?>
```

right before this line:

```
<?php do_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', $checkout); ?>
```

Comment: actually, quite suprisingly so this code was in the `form-billing.php` file. Anyways, I'll mark your answer as correct since you made me go and look in other files and not blindly staring at the `form-checkout.php` and wondering why it doesn't work. Thx!